# GCP CloudSQL, IAM and Hasura

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, hasura

I'm rolling out Hasura on GKE, and I need for it to connect to CloudSQL via IAM.

While most of the tutorials online describe the use of k8s secrets for usernames and passwords, I would like for Hasura to connect via IAM. That means no passwords.

What's the best way to craft the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL` to make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end it was postgres' `paramspec` to the rescue. By crafting the connection string as follows for the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL`:

`postgres://localhost:5432/mydatabase?user=my-service-account@gcp-project.iam`

I was able connect successfully, with `workload-identity` and a sidecar with `cloudsql-proxy` as @kurtisvg suggested

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [*automatic* IAM database authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#log_in_with_automatic), using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy. You can follow the [Connect from GKE](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy) instructions, and just modify the sidecar command to use the `-enable_iam_login` instead of a secret for the password.

Comment: i've added the cloud-sql-auth-proxy as a sidecar next to my hasura pod. I've also `-enabled_iam_login` as well. However, it looks like Hasura still requires cloud-instance-creds as secrets for deployment, which I don't want.

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/deployment/deployment-guides/google-kubernetes-engine-cloud-sql.html

Comment: If you are using [workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#workload-identity), you won't need a service account key. For the other credentials, they are used to specify the "POSTGRES_DB_USER" and "POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD" env vars that Hasaru is using. You'll use the email of the service account for the DB_USER ([described here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#log_in_with_automatic)) and the DB_PASSWORD can by anything you want, as the proxy will automatically replace it. If HASURA forces you to pick something, you can use " ".

Comment: You also don't have to use secrets to populate the environment variables: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#log_in_with_automatic